# Converting matching characters after a specific keyword in a line that starts with SUM

Tags: regex

I'm having some difficulties in changing characters after a certain keyword (in this case it's FOR) in a line that starts with SUM

Example:

```
SUM A+b+c TO var FOR D->E='' AND G->H=''
```

Expected Result:

```
SUM A+b+c To var FOR D:Field("E")='' AND G:Field("H")=''
```

Again any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Andy

Comment: So `X->Y=Z` should be substituted with `X:Field("Y")=Z` *if* line starts with `SUM`? BTW: Which language?

Comment: @jensgram yes that's the idea. The language I'm using is xBase++, but I will apply the regular expression changes for the xbase++ code using PHP.

Comment: Is `D->E=''` -> `D:Field("E")` a typo? Or is `G->H=''` -> `G:Field("H")=''`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replace itself can be achieved with the following:

```
<?php

$str = "SUM A+b+c TO var FOR D->E='' AND G->H=''";

print preg_replace('/([A-Z]+)->([A-Z]+)=([^\s]+)/', '\\1:Field("\\2")=\\3', $str);
```

([Example](http://www.ideone.com/ykGD8))

This does not, however, check that the string starts with `SUM`. You could incorporate a simple `substr()` check: `if (substr($str, 0, 4) === 'SUM ') { ... }`, see [working demo](http://www.ideone.com/EqvJM).